# Remove duplicate string in multiple lines

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, audacity

Okay, so I have a big ol' beat finder label output from Audacity that looks like this:

```
25.651000            25.651000
25.666000            25.666000
25.685000            25.685000
25.718000            25.718000
25.737000            25.737000
26.244000            26.244000
27.050425            27.052000
27.853000            27.853000
27.867000            27.867000
28.674000            28.674000
```

However, as you can see Audacity decided to duplicate the first column twice. However, I don't want that second column. Is there anyway to delete that second column leaving me with something like this?

```
25.651000
25.666000
25.685000
25.718000
25.737000
26.244000
27.050425
27.853000
27.867000
28.674000
```

There are about 186 lines.

Comment: A simple cut or awk will do.

Comment: Do you have one space before your data, or does value starts from beginning of line?

Comment: Sorry, no space accidentally added that in formatting everything. Fixed.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that you feel best solved your problem so that future visitors know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it for you;

`cut -f 1 -d ' ' MyFile.txt`

Results in:

```
25.651000
25.666000
25.685000
25.718000
25.737000
26.244000
27.050425
27.853000
27.867000
28.674000
```

Comment: You should not use  `cat` with programs that can read data itself.  It slows things down, uses more resources, loss of functionality. So `cut -f 1 -d ' ' MyFile.txt`.  You code does not produce output you have from above data, just blank lines, since OP has space before his data in example above.

Comment: @Jotne updated per your comments. Even though OP said he was good. :)

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
awk '$0=$1' MyFile.txt
25.651000
25.666000
25.685000
25.718000
25.737000
26.244000
27.050425
27.853000
27.867000
28.674000
```

This is more secure, se Eds comment.

```
awk '{print $1}' MyFile.txt
```

Comment: That first one will fail if $1 evaluates numerically to zero (e.g. `00.000000`).

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP ' \K[^ ]+' file
```

Output:

```
25.651000
25.666000
25.685000
25.718000
25.737000
26.244000
27.052000
27.853000
27.867000
28.674000
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/ .*//' YourFile
```

remove anything since first space until the end

Answer (score 1):

There is `sed` for you:

```
sed 's/\(^.*\) .*$/\1/' file
```

Comment: move the space char outside the group, it is not part of the value

Comment: right, it ask to remove the duplicate, not to have a single clean value. You got the point